# Reading extra properties or host addresses inside the JSON test case

Tags: testing

I am using `zerocode-rest-bdd` maven lib with following version. I have my applications host and port defined in the JUnit runner with "@TargetEnv("app_host.properties")".

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jsmart</groupId>
  <artifactId>zerocode-rest-bdd</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.15</version>
</dependency>
```

I want to access more hosts/ports(boundary application IPs) and common tokens(SAML, OAuth etc) into my JSON test case which I am unable to access using `${{app_host}}`.

Is there any other way to extend or configure these extra properties so that I can access them and validate my boundary contracts?

app_host.properties contains:

```
web.application.endpoint.host=https://api.github.local
web.application.endpoint.port=443
web.application.endpoint.context=
#Can not access these below properties
app_host_1=https://app1.host.local.uk
saml_token=<SAML>sdf-wer</SAML>
```

Accessing in the test case as below:

```
"url": "${app_host_1}/users/u123",
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using an older version of Zerocode lib. You can update to `<version>1.2.17</version>` or to the [latest](https://search.maven.org/search?q=zerocode-tdd) as below.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jsmart</groupId>
  <artifactId>zerocode-tdd</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.x</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, once you define your properties e.g.

```
micro_host_1=https://micro.host1.local.uk
xyz_key=abc_value
```

the values can be resolved via `${micro_host_1}` or `${xyz_key}` to, `https://micro.host1.local.uk` or `abc_value` respectively in the test cases.

Hope this helps!